# How to get rid of body odor (a difficult case)?

Tags: baking-soda, body-odor

I have body odor and make my whole life have problem

I went to see a couple doctors, but they did not have any solutions

Every day I take shower before I go to work, but people can smell my odor as early as finished shower for only 1 hour.

Please do not ask me take showers twice a day, eat green and similar things, I did all that already

I am looking something that people may not know but work. For example, I had strong foot odor for years, but I found that put baking soda into shoes will magically eliminate the smell within a couple days.

Comment: Do you use deodorant?

Comment: It is form the whole body, not just underarm. Moreover, it would be super odor if I mix deodorant with my body odor

Comment: Maybe this has to do with the type of soap and shampoo that you use. Try one that eliminates a high percentage of germs. As we know there are a lot of types of soaps, ones with lots of fragrance, creams, oils, artificial colors, etc. Try one that eliminates virus and the most neutral possible i.e. with no oils,  creams, etc. The same for your shampoo choice. And as a final tip, maybe use parfum? and changing your clothes daily.